# Finding the value within a sum which increases events within a duration.

Tags: calculus, summation

Alright this is a lengthy topic, mainly because I have a real world application I'm trying to model, so I'll start there and reduce it to the math (Forewarning, I have a *very* basic understanding of Calculus)

I am designing a game, within this game characters attack automatically at intervals defined by their weapon (there are other increases, but they, along with the effects of dual wielding can be ignored for this). There is an effect I'm planning on using which will activate when the character attacks and it is not active. While active, it increases the character's attack speed based on some value I'll call *x*. When the character attacks again while the effect is active, it further increases their speed by that same *x*. To be clear, this means after attack $i$, your speed, $s$, would be
$$\frac{s}{1+xi}$$
Now this effect will have a static duration, $d$. Intuitively, when that that duration ends, that speed increase is lost. My goal (in order to avoid the easier, but awkward feeling, solution of simply shortening $d$) is that if the value of the effect is some number $m$, which represents the new relative average attack speed, as in $\frac{s}{m}$, how do I find $x$?

Obviously I'm aware that for the same $m$, $x$ will shrink as $s$ does. I've done a decent amount of experimenting and playing with the algebra and attempting to somehow model useful data related to this graphically, but I've found I'm a little out of my depth. Best I've been able to find is an equation where $y=0$ at an $x$ value which results in an exactly even amount of attacks within duration $d$. As I said at the top, my knowledge of Calculus is minimal, but from what I do know I think my answer lies somewhere there, given that time to complete all (full) attacks can be modeled with

### $$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{md}{s}\rfloor} \frac{s}{1+xi}$$

Not sure if I provided enough info or not, but to recap:

- $s =$ Weapon Speed in Seconds
- $d =$ Duration of Effect
- $m =$ Relative average speed of weapon over a full cycle $(\frac{s}{m})$
- $x =$ The answer! But descriptively the additive modifier to speed on each attack.

Giving me a cheat code (The straight up answer) is fine, as I can likely work backwards to understand, but an explanation would be exemplary! Thanks in advance.

Edit: I want to clarify a couple things based on Matti's comments. Firstly, although a little backwards from a purely mathematical point of view, in games "attack speed" is usually measured in the amount of *time* it takes to make an attack, i.e. 4 seconds. So when I say "increasing speed", I mean increasing the amount of attacks within that duration $s$. Secondly, my belief that there is a *continuous* way to model $x$ hinges on the assumption that since $\frac{md}{s}$ is continuous, and it can be described as an average within the time it takes to complete a full "cycle" of this effect (from when it is triggered until it ends and is triggered again), there should be a *continuous* way to model how $x$ changes it. If this is wrong, I'd love to know why, as it might be the key to why I've struggled to solve this.

Edit 2: Okay so I've managed to find an equation which crosses the X-axis at the proper value. So I can rephrase my question as "I need to find a way to output the value where $y=0$ in this function:"

### $$\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil\frac{md}{s}\rceil - 1} \frac{s}{1+xi} + \frac{s-(\lceil\frac{md}{s}\rceil\frac{s}{m} - d)}{1+\lceil\frac{md}{s}\rceil x} - d$$

For those wondering, this models all attacks besides the final one in an effect, then adds whatever partial that last attack is (even when it's 1) over its respective modifier, then since those all add up to the full duration of the effect, subtracting that means $y=0$ is the $x$ value which gives $\frac{md}{s}$ attacks within $d$

Comment: I don't really understand the wording. You say that the speed is increasing, yet you **divide** $s$ by some value that is greater than one. Wouldn't that decrease the speed? Anyway, it seems like your "speed" is not the same speed as of a car, for example, with the units something like *one divided by time*. Perhaps instead of "speed", you mean something like "duration".

Comment: You're right, my phrasing is inconsistent. There is a difference there in that "speed" is the time it takes to make an attack, so it would really be increasing the "speed" by reducing the duration denoted by s.

Comment: So mathematically speaking, it seems like you want to calculate a sum like
$$
\sum_{i=1}^L \frac{1}{1+ix}
$$
for some upper limit $L$ (notice that for a constant $s$, you can take it as a factor for this). I don't think that there are any simpler ways of evaluating this than making a short code that calculates it. Otherwise you would need something like a digamma function, so it's not going to be easy anyway. Just for curiosity: as $L$ approaches infinity, the sum diverges.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%281%2Bnx%29%2C+n%3D1+to+L

Comment: That sum wouldn't actually help. For one, the limit isn't exactly useful information, as the number of iterations will always be finite and relatively small (if d is 1, it's unreasonable for a computer to calculate 100 attacks within that duration). Secondly, that only ever accounts for *integer* amounts of attacks within d, and I can already model that.

Comment: It might help us if you [edit] the question to show us a graph of how $s$ depends on $i$ for various values of the other parameters. Make it easy for us to see the general shape of the function you want.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how. That's part of the problem, I don't exactly how how to model it in the first place. I have a rough understanding that there are "break points" where the duration of the cycle equals $d$, and progressing past that increases the number of times it iterates, but beyond that I'm not sure how to write a function that describes that change.